# Get all reports where id is only present in one table and id match

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, join

Ok, I have and unread report table and report table, on click of a button the `StaffID` and `ReportID` gets send the read table (`Read_Report`).

I can retrieve all read reports matching the staffid *(query 1)*

I can get all reports that are not in both tables but only in reports *(query 2)*.

However in query 2 I need to get reports that are 1 nor read, and 2 related to the session ID.

**report**

- ReportID (PK)

Is there any way i can get this working ?

**Read_Report**

- StaffID (FK)
- ReportID (FK)

**report**

**Working**  *(query 1)*

```
 function get_read_report()
        {
            $this->db->select('report.Report_Name, report.ReportDate, report.ReportID')
                ->from('report')
                ->join('Read_Report', 'report.ReportID = Read_Report.ReportID')
                ->where('Read_Report.StaffID', $this->session->userdata("StaffID"));
            $result = $this->db->get();
            return $result->result();// fetch data then return
        }
```

**Not individual to the user** *(query 2)*.

```
    function get_unread_report()
    {
        $this->db->select('report.Report_Name, report.ReportDate, report.ReportID')
            ->from('report')
            ->join('Read_Report', 'report.ReportID = Read_Report.ReportID', 'left')
            ->where('Read_Report.ReportID IS NULL');
//            ->where('Read_Report.StaffID',$this->session->userdata("StaffID"));
        $result = $this->db->get();
        return $result->result();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there is not enough information in the question to provide any answer. Let me explain why.

If I understand the question correctly you need to get records from the `report` table which have not been read and thus do not have any related records in the `Read_Report` table but at the same time have some reference to the `$this->session->userdata("StaffID")`. Is this correct?

We do *not* know if the `report` table has any references to `StaffID` or if any other table exists which references both `ReportID` in the `report` table and `StaffID`. In short we have no idea how the `report` is related to the stuff id except the table which tells us that someone read the report.

Most likely there should be a table or some logic which defines if `StaffID` has access to the report. Using this logic we might list all reports available for given `StaffID` and thus related to the session ID.

In general the question might be - what does it mean 'reports related to the session ID'? How they are related? If we do not know the answer to this question we can not answer yours.

Comment: Yeah, the StaffID is not in the reports table only in Read_Reports, I think I need to restructure the database to relate more the the StaffID, The StaffID is stored in the Read_Report table on button click, but nothing in the report table as anyone can read the report. +! for pointing out the Logic.

Comment: I see. I suggest to accept the answer to make sure other people do not spend time and study the question which looks already solved.

You are right that you need to define the notion of `report is related to staff id` somehow if you will. May be think about why some of the reports are not related and build a criteria based on this.